# SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to establish an SSL connection in a Java client-server application. I have provided a JKS keystore with the complete certificate chain, but I'm still getting the following exception in the server:

```
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
fatal error: 42: null cert chain
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
%% Invalidated:  [Session-5, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
MyThread
, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  
fatal, 
description = bad_certificate
MyThread, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
MyThread, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
Stack Trace
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1521) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:528) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1197) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1165) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:318) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:306) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientCertificate(ServerHandshaker.java:1939) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:232) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:970) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:967) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1459) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    ... 2 more
```

This is **not caused by a lack of certificates**. Earlier in the debug, we see the following certificates, which are in the correct order for SSL (most specific first, root ca last):

```
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=ABC
  ...
  Issuer: CN=DEF
  ...
]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=DEF
  ...
  Issuer: CN=GHI
  ...
]
chain [2] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GHI
  ...
  Issuer: CN=GHI
  ...
]
```

So can someone tell me why this is occurring? Could it be that the client is rejecting the certificates?

Note: the keys and certificates were provided by another party; I can't just generate my own.

Comment: You've omitted and redacted too much to be certain, but it is possible that the cert chain you (found and) posted is for the _server_, while this exception occurred (definitely, per the stacktrace) because the server requested client authentication (aka mutual auth(entication) or 2way auth(entication) or client cert(ificate)) and the _client_ sent an empty/null chain i.e. sent _no_ cert(s). No, the client is not rejecting the certs, or anything else.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, you are correct. Post an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Comment: In case anybody else is trying to build a distributed network, and their clients aren't sending any certs, make the servers return an empty array for their TrustManager's `getAcceptedIssuers`.  Example code here https://github.com/Erhannis/TlsChannelTest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is **not** the server's certificate chain. The server is rejecting the connection because it is expecting the client to authenticate itself. I think we can tell this because the stack trace includes `ServerHandshaker.clientCertificate()`.

Java's SSL engine requires client authentication only if you call [SSLEngine.setNeedClientAuth()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html#setNeedClientAuth-boolean-).

Comment: `dave_thompson_085` should get the credit for figuring this out, but I can't award him the answer because he posted the answer as a comment. I posted the answer so I could mark this question as answered.

Comment: BTW can you please tell me what are the changes you made on client-side to avoid the above exception? I am facing the similar issue with a thirdaprty server which i don't have control over server side

Answer (score 1):

I got the above exception when the server's truststore did not contain the CA. The server did not include the CA in its CertificateRequest and so the client had no option but to return an empty list. I had imported fullchain.pem from LetsEncrypt certbot into the truststore, but this doesn't seem to include letsencryptauthorityx3.pem.
Solved by downloading letsencryptauthorityx3.pem from https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias letsencryptauthorityx3 -file letsencryptauthorityx3.pem -keystore truststore.ks

Comment: I am having the same issue: client not sending any certificate on handhsake when clientAuth in tomcat ="want" or receiving fatal error: 42: null cert chain
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain on serverside logs when clientAuth"yes" on tomcat. What  am I doing wrong? Here is my question in full detail
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739087/client-certificate-authentication-through-tomcat-and-spring-shows-certificate-as