# client certificate authentication through Tomcat And Spring shows certificate as null in X509AuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security, x509certificate

I know there are similar posts as to why the certificate - certs variable blow -  in Spring Filter in `X509AuthenticationFilter.java` comes out null

```
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[])((X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate"));
```

By reading this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24466384/2181576), I realized that I could print the TLS handshake and get details into what is going wrong. Prima Facie, I am of the opinion that the client is not sending the certificate. If I am not wrong, then at this point

```
 Cert Authorities:
<CN=*.mycompanyname.com>
*** ServerHelloDone
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-4, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4972
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 7
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

instead of empty, accordting to this blog - [how to analyse Java SSL errors](https://dzone.com//articles/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors), if the client would have sent the client certificate, it would have a response something like

```
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: CN=Application 3, OU=Smartjava, O=Smartjava, L=NL, ST=ZH, C=NL
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 90655907749318585147523875906892969031300830816947226352221659107570169820452561428696751943383590982109524990627182456571533992582229229163232831159652561902456847954385746762477844009336466314872376131553489447601649924116778337873632641536164462534398137791450495316700015095054427027256393580022887087767
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Mon Mar 12 15:13:24 CET 2012,
               To: Tue Mar 12 15:13:24 CET 2013]
  Issuer: CN=Application CA, OU=Smartjava, O=Smartjava, L=Maasland, ST=ZH, C=NL
  SerialNumber: [    b247ffb2 ce060768]

]
```

As there are lots of pieces of gettin this right (trust store, keystore, tomcat configuration, creating the certificates well, knowing where to place what artifacts), it seems to me to have an initial heavy lifting before getting this right. Not to mention there being two strategies to do this - a) No neccessity to keep client ceritifcates in trust store rather only keeping CA authority certificate in trust store and only using it to sign client certificates and b) placing all client certificates in the trust store

I have followed the first approach presented in this blog post [X.509 client certificates with Spring Security](https://blog.codecentric.de/x-509-client-certificates-with-spring-security)

What I have done?
I have a CA certifite issued by `GoGetSSL RSA DV CA, O=GoGetSSL, L=Riga, C=LV`

I am using it as my CA authority that will sign client certificates. Hence I have placed this in the trust store. I placed it in the truststore by doing

keytool -import -file servercert_2022.crt -alias serverCA -keystore truststore.jks

It looks like

```
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: serverca
Creation date: Dec 9, 2022
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=*.mycompanyname.com
Issuer: CN=GoGetSSL RSA DV CA, O=GoGetSSL, L=Riga, C=LV
Serial number: 2a49d139988338b92dee3274c70e8428
Valid from: Tue Nov 29 05:30:00 IST 2022 until: Sat Dec 30 05:29:59 IST 2023
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  82:4D:8C:61:CD:D8:65:60:99:78:F3:D2:7E:B3:73:30
         SHA1: 4D:DC:24:25:5A:67:41:E7:4D:FF:1A:B3:F8:B6:7E:A1:17:B0:58:A0
         SHA256: 2E:24:AF:0A:8C:25:B7:D5:89:06:3E:DC:08:FA:2D:69:A4:DF:58:8F:E4:                                                                                                                                  08:AB:DD:EB:EE:2C:1D:2B:EA:EC:DD
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
0000: 04 82 01 69 01 67 00 75   00 AD F7 BE FA 7C FF 10  ...i.g.u........
0010: C8 8B 9D 3D 9C 1E 3E 18   6A B4 67 29 5D CF B1 0C  ...=..>.j.g)]...   


#2: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://crt.usertrust.com/GoGetSSLRCA.crt
,
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.usertrust.com
]
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F9 FB 50 C4 8B 67 BB 67   64 FE 83 21 A6 A9 CE 3F  ..P..g.gd..!...?
0010: 55 84 93 99                                        U...
]
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.usertrust.com/GoGetSSLRSCA.crl]
]]

#6: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.2.2.64]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 19 68 74 74 70 73 3A   2F 2F 63 70 73 2E 75 73  ..https://                                                                                                                                  cps.us
0010: 65 72 74 72 75 73 74 2E   63 6F 6D                 ertrust.com

]]  ]
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
[]  ]
]

#7: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

#8: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

#9: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: *.mycompanyname.com
  DNSName: mycompanyname.com
]

#10: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 84 D5  F7 50 98 94 E8  .......G..d.P...
0010: B8 63 D4 B5                                        .c..
]
]
```

---

I added my certificate-key to keystore by

My key is a in keystore.p12 file. I read that the key along with server certificate can be placed in the keystore by doing this

```
winpty openssl pkcs12 -export -in servercert_2022.crt -inkey private.pem -certfile servercert_2022.crt -out keystore.p12
```

Keystore looks like this

```
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: 1
Creation date: Dec 9, 2022
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 3
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=*.mycompanyname.com
Issuer: CN=GoGetSSL 
Serial number: 2a0e8428
Valid from: Tue Nov 29 05:30:00 IST 2022 until: Sat Dec 30 05:29:59 IST 2023
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  82:4D:8C:61:CD:D8:65:60:99:78:F3:D2:7E:B3:73:30
         SHA1: 4D:DC:24:25:5A:67:41:E7:4D:FF:1A:B3:F8:B6:7E:A1:17:B0:58:A0
         SHA256: 2E:24:AF:0A:8C:25:B7:D5:89:06:3E:DC:08:FA:2D:69:A4:DF:58:8F:E4:08:AB:DD:EB:EE:2C:1D:2B:EA:EC:DD
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
0000: 04 82 01 69 01 67 00 75   00 AD F7 BE FA 7C FF 10  ...i.g.u......
0160: 16 84 D3 72 78 21 62 96   FA 96 A7 55 D5           ...rx!b....U.


#2: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://crt.usertrust.com/GoGetSSLADVCA.crt
,
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.usertrust.com
]
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F9 FB 50 C4 8B 67 BB 67   64 FE 83 21 A6 A9 CE 3F  ..P..g.gd..!...?
0010: 55 84 93 99                                        U...
]
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.usertrust.com/GoGetSSLADVCA.crl]
]]

#6: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.2.64]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 19 68 74 74 70 73 3A   2F 2F 63 70 73 2E 75 73  ..https://cps.us
0010: 65 72 74 72 75 73 74 2E   63 6F 6D                 ertrust.com

]]  ]
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
[]  ]
]

#7: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

#8: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

#9: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: *.mycompanyname.com
  DNSName: mycompanyname.com
]

#10: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 84 D5 11 9F 12 AB 0A 47   D3 DD 64 F7 50 98 94 E8  .......G..d.P...
0010: B8 63 D4 B5                                        .c..
]
]

Certificate[2]:
Owner: CN=GoGetSSL RSA DV CA, O=GoGetSSL, L=Riga, C=LV
Issuer: CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, ST=New Jersey, C=US
Serial number: 938bb08e62987b4f75f98cb6a5045c96
Valid from: Thu Sep 06 05:30:00 IST 2018 until: Wed Sep 06 05:29:59 IST 2028
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  4E:81:90:9E:43:B3:18:66
         SHA1: 07:0A:72:6C:6E:44:18:DC:F
         SHA256: 43:CA:C3:1E:F8:E8:BA:1B:4B:16:B8:20:6E:4C:0A:26:C5:BA:D:C2:FD:64
Signature algorithm name: SHA384withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://crt.usertrust.com/USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
,
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.usertrust.com
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 53 79 BF 5A AA 2B 4A CF   54 80 E1 D8 9B C0 9D F2  Sy.Z.+J.T.......
0010: B2 03 66 CB                                        ..f.
]
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:0
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.usertrust.com/USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crl]
]]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3..2.2.64]
[]  ]
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
[]  ]
]

#6: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

#7: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

#8: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F9 FB 50 C4 8B 67 BB 67   64 FE 83 21 A6 A9 CE 3F  ..P..g.gd..!...?
0010: 55 84 93 99                                        U...
]
]

Certificate[3]:
Owner: CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, ST=New Jersey, C=US
Issuer: CN=AAA Certificate Services, O=Comodo CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
Serial number: 3972443af922b751d7d36c10dd313595
Valid from: Tue Mar 12 05:30:00 IST 2019 until: Mon Jan 01 05:29:59 IST 2029
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  28:5E:C9:09:C4:AB:0D:2D:57:F5:08:6B:22:57:99:AA
         SHA1: D8:9E:3B:D4:3D:5D:90:9B:47:A1:89:77:AA:9D:5C:E3:6C:EE:18:4C
         SHA256: 68:B9:C7:61:21:9A:5B:1F:01:31:78:44:74:66:5D:B6:1B:BD:B1:09:E0:0F:05:CA:9F:74:24:4E:E5:F5:F5:2B
Signature algorithm name: SHA384withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 4096-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.comodoca.com
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: A0 11 0A 23 3E 96 F1 07   EC E2 AF 29 EF 82 A5 7F  ...#>......)....
0010: D0 30 A4 B4                                        .0..
]
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.comodoca.com/AAACertificateServices.crl]
]]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.5.29.32.0]
[]  ]
]

#6: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

#7: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 53 79 BF 5A AA 2B 4A CF   54 80 E1 D8 9B C0 9D F2  Sy.Z.+J.T.......
0010: B2 03 66 CB                                        ..f.
]
]



*******************************************
```

My tomcat connector looks like this

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
            clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLS" 
            keystoreFile="C:\Company\keys\keystore.p12"
            keystoreType="PKCS12" keystorePass="password"
            truststoreFile="C:\Company\keys\truststore.jks"
            truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="password"/>
```

My spring security configuration looks like this

```
<http pattern="/api/mutualauthenticationtest"  create-session="never"
          authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
          entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

          use-expressions="true">

        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," />

    </http>
```

With the above configuration the debugger is able to reach inside the `X509AuthenticationFilter.java` class at this place at the line with variable certs

```
private X509Certificate extractClientCertificate(HttpServletRequest request) {
        X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[])((X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate"));
        if (certs != null && certs.length > 0) {
            if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.logger.debug("X.509 client authentication certificate:" + certs[0]);
            }

            return certs[0];
        } else {
            if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.logger.debug("No client certificate found in request.");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

for the API curl API request that I make to this API. The curl request has my client certificate attached

```
curl -k --location --request POST 'https://localhost:8443/api/mutualauthenticationtest' \

--header 'clientid: 3' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=464646778768678678676' \
--cert client.crt \
--key clientprivate.key \
--data-raw '{"userID":"someuserid"}'
```

The client.crt in the curl request was generated with the help of client.csr (signing request), client private key and signed by the server certificate and server private key.

client private key

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out clientprivate.key -passout pass:someclientpassword 2048
```

client csr

```
winpty openssl req -new -key clientprivate.key -out client.csr
```

Initially, I had created my own CA server certificate with CN localhost. But after reading some comments on SO, I used a genuine Server certificate with CN:mycompanyname.com. I also created  the client CSR with the CN=somesubdomain.mycompanyname.com so that it matches the domain *.mycompanyname.com

Here's how the  client certificate was created

```
winpty openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA servercert_2022.crt -CAkey private.pem -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 365 -sha256
```

Placing below the entire handshake if it helps someone help me get to the bottom of this.

```
    https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-4, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 512
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -2129767729 bytes = { 47, 24, 48, 232, 111, 34, 57, 141, 51, 1, 246, 45, 164, 70, 153, 138, 39, 181, 40, 12, 168, 95, 109, 1, 194, 50, 38, 131 }
Session ID:  {}

*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=*.mycompanyname.com
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 2622705370403332787775762243661727944626694756503406987897017427384873636985758217173690153198533118362188933540538596405165697331
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Nov 29 00:00:00 UTC 2022,
               To: Fri Dec 29 23:59:59 UTC 2023]
  Issuer: CN=GoGetSSL RSA DV CA, O=GoGetSSL, L=Riga, C=LV
  SerialNumber: [    2a49d139 988338b9 2dee3274 c70e8428]

Certificate Extensions: 10
[3]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 82 01 6D 04 82 01 69   01 67 00 75 00 AD F7 BE  ...m...i.g.u....
0010: FA 7C FF 10 C8 8B 9D 3D   9C 1E 3E 18 6A B4 67 29  .......=..>.j.g)

0170: D5                                                 .


[3]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://crt.usertrust.com/GoGetSSLRSADVCA.crt
, 
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.usertrust.com
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F9 FB 50 C4 8B 67 BB 67   64 FE 83 21 A6 A9 CE 3F  ..P..g.gd..!...?
0010: 55 84 93 99                                        U...
]
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.usertrust.com/GoGetSSLRSADVCA.crl]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.2.64]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 19 68 74 74 70 73 3A   2F 2F 63 70 73 2E 75 73  ..https://cps.us
0010: 65 72 74 72 75 73 74 2E   63 6F 6D                 ertrust.com

]]  ]
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
[]  ]
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: *.mycompanyname.com
  DNSName: mycompanyname.com
]

[10]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 84 D5 11 9F 12 AB 0A 47   D3 DD 64 F7 50 98 94 E8  .......G..d.P...
0010: B8 63 D4 B5                                        .c..
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 41 55 D9 6E D1 C1 7E E1   CE D9 DA 01 D6 83 94 7C  AU.n............
0010: EF 9E 27 3A 46 9C B1 32   9A E9 C3 1E 36 8E 1C 71  ..':F..2....6..q


]
chain [3] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GoGetSSL 
  Signature Algorithm: SHA384withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.12

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 2016675053399680968778139946606275282233371636099081255780548426567610365288242376854592612489780940673622601461569960956302879926833060318530351
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Sep 06 00:00:00 UTC 2018,
               To: Tue Sep 05 23:59:59 UTC 2028]
  Issuer: CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, ST=New Jersey, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    938bb08e 62987b4f 75f98cb6 a5045c96]

Certificate Extensions: 8
[3]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://crt.usertrust.com/USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
, 
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.usertrust.com
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 53 79 BF 5A AA 2B 4A CF   54 80 E1 D8 9B C0 9D F2  Sy.Z.+J.T.......
0010: B2 03 66 CB                                        ..f.
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:0
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.usertrust.com/USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crl]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.2.64]
[]  ]
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
[]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F9 FB 50 C4 8B 67 BB 67   64 FE 83 21 A6 A9 CE 3F  ..P..g.gd..!...?
0010: 55 84 93 99                                        U...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA384withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 5D 74 43 28 78 80 E4 33   A1 34 AB 33 B7 06 B2 73  ]tC(x..3.4.3...s

01F0: 3C 4D 84 C0 E6 21 79 E3   11 E5 AB 16 F0 19 42 19  <M...!y.......B.

]
chain [3] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, ST=New Jersey, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA384withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.12

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 4096 bits
  modulus: 52248758361752507534246388533722547304608772308115673058706321503049610972993225326579926576629493740386532378470836364707455134729548367373189550921756904777340153719441907345834660183638543
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Mar 12 00:00:00 UTC 2019,
               To: Sun Dec 31 23:59:59 UTC 2028]
  Issuer: CN=AAA Certificate Services, O=Comodo CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  SerialNumber: [    3972443a f922b751 d7d36c10 dd313595]

Certificate Extensions: 7
[3]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.comodoca.com
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: A0 11 0A 23 3E 96 F1 07   EC E2 AF 29 EF 82 A5 7F  ...#>......)....
0010: D0 30 A4 B4                                        .0..
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.comodoca.com/AAACertificateServices.crl]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.5.29.32.0]
[]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 53 79 BF 5A AA 2B 4A CF   54 80 E1 D8 9B C0 9D F2  Sy.Z.+J.T.......
0010: B2 03 66 CB                                        ..f.
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA384withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 18 87 51 DC 74 21 3D 9C   8A E0 27 B7 33 D0 2E CC  ..Q.t!=...'.3...

00F0: 7F 8E 76 72 99 0C 9D FE   D7 91 08 16 A1 A3 5F 95  ..vr.........._.

]
***
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 19352321750303628830904646093808624566974313423482165871643805927488532053250
  public y coord: 45496769771360840433108417226772017731510614660888440135094323373501113499217
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=*.mycompanyname.com>
*** ServerHelloDone
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-4, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4972
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 7
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 70
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 53, 247, 204, 77, 62, 51, 36, 140, 49, 178, 158, 159, 179, 238, 225, 234, 153, 124, 198, 178, 83, 148, 252, 78, 0, 17, 70, 200, 87, 141, 60, 255, 50, 144, 12, 181, 38, 254, 238, 59, 9, 254, 105, 34, 65, 212, 57, 27, 115, 17, 41, 88, 128, 128, 253, 149, 157, 18, 174, 252, 114, 131, 231, 6 }
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: BE E4 A9 B5 9D A7 F6 60   18 98 9B E6 CA 24 4D FA  .......`.....$M.
0010: 91 B6 4A 02 37 D1 C1 F3   2D 74 30 EF 64 05 AC 35  ..J.7...-t0.d..5
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 81 0E 53 CF 2F 18 30 E8   6F 22 39 8D 33 01 F6 2D  ..S./.0.o"9.3..-
0010: A4 46 99 8A 27 B5 28 0C   A8 5F 6D 01 C2 32 26 83  .F..'.(.._m..2&.
Server Nonce:
0000: 63 92 B1 A6 7F 81 DC C2   3B E7 19 A6 A4 FC 5F D8  c.......;....._.
0010: AC 17 FC 60 C9 3D E8 A2   A7 C0 CE 82 62 0F F4 21  ...`.=......b..!
Master Secret:
0000: 7E 20 23 1F 02 34 2E 40   73 18 5F 5A 09 F4 B6 28  . #..4.@s._Z...(
0010: 1B 30 D2 F3 2E A8 85 BA   72 2F FC 79 57 2C F3 5B  .0......r/.yW,.[
0020: 70 E8 81 50 90 D4 DB 3C   4E 7D 89 A8 A1 68 EC DC  p..P...<N....h..
... no MAC keys used for this cipher   
0000: A8 B8 56 36                                        ..V6
Server write IV:
0000: 5F 42 7E 2E
```

What could I be possibly doing wrong that the client is unable to send the certificate (if my conjecture is right) or simply, why the certs variable is null when the certificate is being read from inside the request.getAttribute() mentioned in the very first line of this post? Any help will be immensely appreciated.